# Gumby Framework - JQuery firing onclick event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gumby-framework

I'm creating a new site with the Gumby CSS Framework: http://gumbyframework.com

When I use their JQuery to check for button click and wrap inside their Gumby JS ready function

```
Gumby.ready(function() {});
```

The event is fired twice. I've spent a while trying to debug and cant work it out.

CodePen demo here: http://codepen.io/ptimson/pen/LseFk?editors=101

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Button</a></div>
```

**JS**

```
// Gumby is ready to go
Gumby.ready(function() {

  $('#btn').on(Gumby.click, function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Clicked');
  });
});
```

**Note: Removing Gumby.ready works but I need to keep that function so that I know the Gumby functions are available right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, removing Gumby.ready is ok. According to the Documentation, Gumby will automatically initialize by default. For manual initialization you have to load the script with a flag:

```
<script gumby-init="false" src="js/libs/gumby.js"></script>
```

And than you can call Gumby.init().ready();

Here's the [Documentation](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/javascript/#!/manual-initialization).

Best.